# Loop through a Pandas Dataframe in blocks

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given the following dataframe

```
      open    high     low   close    volume
0     74.090  74.144  74.089  74.136  0.000012
1     74.110  74.143  74.009  74.072  0.000419
2     74.074  74.190  74.063  74.081  0.000223
3     74.100  74.244  74.085  74.182  0.000429
4     74.194  74.222  74.164  74.199  0.000090
5     74.198  74.265  74.181  74.213  0.000071
6     74.223  74.244  74.120  74.174  0.000124
7     74.181  74.229  74.132  74.161  0.000087
8     74.164  74.337  74.126  74.324  0.000299
9     74.303  74.407  74.302  74.400  0.000185
10    74.408  74.440  74.373  74.409  0.000163
11    74.437  74.438  74.399  74.418  0.000208
12    74.428  74.464  74.385  74.385  0.000231
```

How can i loop efficiently through the entire dataframe and get (in a new dataframe) at each row the previous 5 rows including the current one?

Comment: What is your expected output? It'll help to have the output dataframe explicitly posted as part of your question.

Comment: my expected output within the loop is a new data-frame for every iteration consisting of 5 rows with all of the columns in the original datafram frame. I will do some logic on it and then save the result in a new column at the same row nr

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want efficiency, use `numpy`'s strides

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided as stride

sr, sc = v.strides
data = stride(v, (v.shape[1], v.shape[0] - 4, 5), (sc, sr, sr))

pn5 = pd.Panel(data, df.columns, df.index[4:], pd.RangeIndex(5))
df5 = pn5.to_frame()
```

---

```
df5.head(10)

               open    high     low   close    volume
major minor                                          
4     0      74.090  74.144  74.089  74.136  0.000012
      1      74.110  74.143  74.009  74.072  0.000419
      2      74.074  74.190  74.063  74.081  0.000223
      3      74.100  74.244  74.085  74.182  0.000429
      4      74.194  74.222  74.164  74.199  0.000090
5     0      74.110  74.143  74.009  74.072  0.000419
      1      74.074  74.190  74.063  74.081  0.000223
      2      74.100  74.244  74.085  74.182  0.000429
      3      74.194  74.222  74.164  74.199  0.000090
      4      74.198  74.265  74.181  74.213  0.000071
```

---

***example processing***

```
def process(df):
    return df.loc[df.name].tail(2)

print(df5.groupby(level=0).apply(process))

               open    high     low   close    volume
major minor                                          
4     3      74.100  74.244  74.085  74.182  0.000429
      4      74.194  74.222  74.164  74.199  0.000090
5     3      74.194  74.222  74.164  74.199  0.000090
      4      74.198  74.265  74.181  74.213  0.000071
6     3      74.198  74.265  74.181  74.213  0.000071
      4      74.223  74.244  74.120  74.174  0.000124
7     3      74.223  74.244  74.120  74.174  0.000124
      4      74.181  74.229  74.132  74.161  0.000087
8     3      74.181  74.229  74.132  74.161  0.000087
      4      74.164  74.337  74.126  74.324  0.000299
9     3      74.164  74.337  74.126  74.324  0.000299
      4      74.303  74.407  74.302  74.400  0.000185
10    3      74.303  74.407  74.302  74.400  0.000185
      4      74.408  74.440  74.373  74.409  0.000163
11    3      74.408  74.440  74.373  74.409  0.000163
      4      74.437  74.438  74.399  74.418  0.000208
12    3      74.437  74.438  74.399  74.418  0.000208
      4      74.428  74.464  74.385  74.385  0.000231
```

---

***setup***

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
        [74.09, 74.14399999999999, 74.089, 74.13600000000001, 1.2e-05],
        [74.11, 74.143, 74.009, 74.072, 0.00041900000000000005],
        [74.074, 74.19, 74.063, 74.081, 0.000223],
        [74.1, 74.244, 74.085, 74.182, 0.000429],
        [74.194, 74.222, 74.164, 74.199, 9e-05],
        [74.19800000000001, 74.265, 74.181, 74.21300000000001, 7.099999999999999e-05],
        [74.223, 74.244, 74.12, 74.17399999999999, 0.000124],
        [74.181, 74.229, 74.132, 74.161, 8.7e-05],
        [74.164, 74.337, 74.126, 74.324, 0.000299],
        [74.303, 74.407, 74.30199999999999, 74.4, 0.000185],
        [74.408, 74.44, 74.373, 74.40899999999999, 0.00016299999999999998],
        [74.437, 74.438, 74.399, 74.418, 0.00020800000000000001],
        [74.428, 74.464, 74.385, 74.385, 0.000231]
    ], columns=['open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume'])
```

Comment: what if i increase the blocks to 1000. will it decrease efficiency?

Comment: No, this will maintain efficiency

Comment: if i want to do math on it do i need to transform every block back to it's original form?

Comment: You did not specify the form you wanted it in.  You could choose any number of ways to represent it.  I chose one way.  However, I can do math on this as well as do math on other representations.  If there are limiting factors, the chosen representation really depends on what you want to do... and you didn't share that information.

Comment: what i want to do with each block is pass it to a function in it's original form which does some logic on it

Comment: Thank you @piRSquared One last question. How do i increase the block size to lets say 1000. which numbers do i change?

Comment: @RaduS `data = stride(v, (v.shape[1], v.shape[0] + 1 - 1000, 1000), (sc, sr, sr)) `